# HTML in php mail function

Tags: php, html, function, email

I have a contact form on my website so users can send me an email but I have run into a problem.

I want to use an HTML link inside the email and I also want the content the user is sending to me to be formated how they would like it.... let me explain.

If a user sends this:

```
Hello World!

Isnt it a great Day?
```

without using headers to enable html, then it says formated like that when it reaches me.

If I use headers (MIME) to enable html, to also include a link in the email (which I would like to do), then it reaches me as:

```
Hello World!Isnt it a great Day?
```

How can I include html, and also keep the email formatted properly?

Thanks

And hopefully all this makes sense :S

Comment: Well, what hinders you to learn HTML and then make use of the langauge? Which part of HTML in specific don't you understand to express a line break or paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nl2br` on your message - http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

It will replace all newlines with HTML `<br>`

```
$message = nl2br($message, false);
```

The second parameter *is_xhtml* is optional if you want to send an HTML email instead of XHTML

Comment: you should not use XHTML in emails.

Comment: @hakre that's what `nl2br` returns according to examples in the PHP manual.

Comment: Read close, test yourself, use the parameter that's needed to fix/control this.

Comment: @hakre right :) just noticed after sent the message - *$is_xhtml* has to be set to `false`

Comment: @hakre [you should not use html in mails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_email#Security_vulnerabilities) ;)

Comment: @hakre However I can't find any source that says about avoiding XHTML in emails. Both HTML and XHTML are displayed correctly or both stripped out by some clients (e.g. GMail, Hotmail, Yahoo Classic) -[source](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C18/doctype_-_the_black_sheep_of_html_email_design)

Comment: Thank you Zoltan! Works great :) Cookie for you